# Can I use old apache solr indexed data after upgrading apache version?

Tags: apache, solr, drupal-7

I have updated the apache2 version form apache2.2.14 to apache2.4.7 and also apache-solr package form 1.4.x to 4.x.

Before upgradation, I have indexed all the content.

After upgradation, in apache configuration it showing 0% indexed.

is there any way to use old indexing?

Answer (score 2):

Solr / Lucene only upgrades older index formats in smaller increments, so you'll have to at least stop by a 3.x release on the way to be able to use the 1.4 index formats.

I'd also recommend going from 4 to 5 as well, since you're already doing the upgrade now, and will be stuck in the past *again* if you don't do the 5.x upgrade as well (6.0 was just released).

My suggestion is to optimize for easy reindexing, and do that. You'll run into the same issue later, or after doing any major changes to your schema.

Answer (score 0):

> The index format is backward compatible between two consecutive major
>   Solr versions. So a Solr 3.x index is compatible with a Solr 4.x
>   index. However if you have a Solr 1.x index and want to upgrade to
>   Solr 4.x then you would need to first upgrade to Solr 3.x first.

[upgrade between major Solr Versions](https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/203776523-How-to-upgrade-between-major-Solr-Versions)

So you'll have to go via 3.x (as Mats says below) or reindex or use the  IndexUpgrader tool on your index.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html